# What does " -inf " mean in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, math

I am trying to find a mean of spesific column in a dataframe but I take -inf as a result what is that mean ?

```
df [df["col_name1"] == 0]["col_name1"].mean()

result : -inf
```

Comment: If you provide a sample dataset that yields this result, we can explain why you get that result. Without additional info, it seems like you end up dividing a negative number by 0 -- which yields negative infinity.

Comment: I understood the tricky point in my dataset , I created a new column from the df and I realized that it's values summation goes to negative inifinity.Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "negative infinity", which is the result of IEEE 754 directed roundings

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Directed_roundings
- https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html

in stock Python

```py
>>> -math.inf
-inf
```

and in Pandas/NumPy

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.Inf
inf
```

Example of directed rounding

```py
>>> a = 1 * math.inf
>>> a + 100
inf
>>> -a + 100
-inf
```

Comment: I understood the tricky point in my dataset , I created a new column from the df and I realized that it's values summation goes to negative inifinity.Thank you :) @ayhan